# Ajax Click different of move mouse but there is a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm playing with Google Map Api and i use ajax to update sql qith this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#map').click(function() {
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "php/clic.php",
      data: {
        label: "value"
      },
      method: "POST"
    });

    request.done(function() {
      // Do something after its done.
    });
  });
});
```

map si the div of the google map.

The problem is the code clic.php is executed when user is clicking on the div but also if user is clicking to move the map. I don't know ajax a lot, so i want to do a else condition to detect if it s a move/clic instead of a simple clic!

Thx!

Comment: And why you don't use an input, span, label or something with a specific id?

Answer (score 0):

Check `event.target` to see if it's the `#map` element.

```
$("#map".click(function() {
    if (event.target != this) {
        return;
    }
    // rest of function
});
```

Comment: I try but i'm not a good javascript developper, but thank you for your help. I can't use your code. I test but it dont work for me.

I find another code working good. Thx for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Code working for me on Chrome:

```
    (function($){
var $doc = $(document),
moved = false,
pos = {x: null, y: null},
abs = Math.abs,
mclick = {
'mousedown.mclick': function(e) {
pos.x = e.pageX;
pos.y = e.pageY;
moved = false;
},
mouseup.mclick': function(e) {
moved = abs(pos.x - e.pageX) > $.clickMouseMoved.threshold
|| abs(pos.y - e.pageY) > $.clickMouseMoved.threshold;
}
};

$doc.on(mclick);

$.clickMouseMoved = function () {
return moved;
};

$.clickMouseMoved.threshold = 3;
})(jQuery);


// test delegated
$(document).on('click', '#map', function(e) {
if ($.clickMouseMoved()) {
console.log('click aborted');
return;            
}
//console.log('click');
var request = $.ajax({
url: "php/clic.php",
data: { label: "value" },
method: "POST"
});
});

// test bound
$('#map').on('click', function(e) {
if ($.clickMouseMoved()) {
// console.log('click aborted');
return;           
}
var request = $.ajax({
url: "php/clic.php",
data: { label: "value" },
method: "POST"
});
//console.log('click');
});
```